# Firebase Cloud Dependencies for API Level 14

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have created an Android Application on API Level 14. Now we decided to implement Push Notifications for our application. Since GCM is no longer supported, we have no option left other than using FCM. According to android documentation Min SDK for FCM is 14, that's we have. But we don't know what will be the correct classpath and compile dependencies for FCM. Currently we use following:

```
    **App Level Gradle**

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 14
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.infotropy.fcm"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
}
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

**Project Level Gradle**

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**On building, we got following build error:**

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

E:\Projects\Android\Fcm\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v21\values-v21.xml
Error:(12, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(14, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
```

And Many More Errors Like This...

Can we fix these issues by just changing the dependencies, and if yes then please mention the correct dependencies.

**Please Note that our first preference is that we don't want to change the SDK version of our project, since its a very big project and changing the SDK version will result in lots of code change and hassle.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
```

You **can't** use `compileSdkVersion 14` and you have to use `compileSdkVersion 23`

However you should use:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
```

and the latest stable version:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'
```

And finally:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But as I have mentioned we don't want to change the SDK version. Can't we implement FCM on API Level 14? Official android documentation says we can do it with API 14 but don't provide appropriate dependencies for it.

Comment: You can't use api 14 to compile. Don't confuse compileSdk and minSdk. You can compile with 27 and use minSdk=14.

Comment: I've updated the answer. If you want to use 9.2.1 you have to use compileSdk=23 but i don't think it is a good way to use an old version today.